# react render not working with getElementById

Tags: reactjs

Why is the first render working but not the second?

```
// load react library
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

//build first component
/* 
   StorePicker
*/
var StorePicker = React.createClass({

    render : function(){
        return (
            <div>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>hi</p>
              <p>and this is another</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
})


ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker/>,document.querySelector('#main'));

ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker/>,document.getElementById('#main'));
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

which doesn't make any sense as it works in the first case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` takes an id without the `#` prefix as parameter. Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(<StorePicker/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```